# How to create email id on ISPConfig using php?

Tags: php, email

I have ISPConfig server for my site. Now i have to create php script which creates email id for each registered user. please help me for this issue.

My problem is i want to generate email id through php file, like we creates on cpanel.

Comment: Registered user on what? Your question isn't very clear.  Please expand and give more detail if possible.

Answer (score 3):

ISPConfig 3 delivers a remote API using SOAP Protocol.

Check out the API documentation which is in PHP : [Ispconfig-API-Doc](http://benjaminbouvier.fr/files/IspConfig-API-Docs.rar)

Create a remote user in the ISPconfig Panel and then connect to your server with the API.
Then you just have to use the function "mail_user_add" to create email id for each registered user.